# How to use Hudson "Parameterized Build" values in an email

Tags: email, configuration, continuous-integration, hudson

We are running a Hudson build server internally on a project. We send out email every time the server deploys new version.

I would like this email to contain more information, including a username and a reason for the build.

From hudsons documentation on [Parameterized builds](https://web.archive.org/web/20170922183939/http://wiki.hudson-ci.org:80/display/HUDSON/Parameterized%20Build), have added text parameters to the build. I am trying here with two different ones (in order to see what works):

In job configuration `This build is parameterized` i added the following two variables

```
Name:          USER 
Default value: userCAPITALIZED

Name:          user
Default value: userstandard
```

See screenshot of [image: parameterized settings]
<sub>(source: [justaddwater.dk](http://justaddwater.dk/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/hudson-parameterize-settings-243x300.png))</sub>
.

Now, down in the bottom section "Editable Email Notification" i have tried EVERYTHING to retrieve these values.

**What works:** All standard Hudson build variables work. Like `$CHANGES`, `$SVN_REVISION`, etc.

But I have tried the to access the variables `user` and `USER` without any luck. Here is a list of what is not working:

```
subject: test of parametrized mail 1user:${env.user}, 2USER:${USER}, 3$USER, 4${ENV, USER}, 5%USER%,stop

more tests
${env, user}
${env, USER}
${ENV, user}
${ENV, USER}
${user}
${USER}
${env.user}
${ENV.user}
${env.USER}
${ENV.USER}
$user
$USER
%user%
%USER%

changes $CHANGES
changes ${CHANGES}
subversion revision: $SVN_REVISION
subversion revision: ${SVN_REVISION}
```

[image: Screenshot of email configuration]
<sub>(source: [justaddwater.dk](http://justaddwater.dk/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/hudson-email-configuration-parameters-300x171.png))</sub>

This merely results in an email with this content:

```
test of parametrized mail 1user:${env.user}, 2USER:${USER}, 3$USER, 4${ENV, USER}, 5%USER%,stop

more tests
${env, user}
${env, USER}
${ENV, user}
${ENV, USER}
${user}
${USER}
${env.user}
${ENV.user}
${env.USER}
${ENV.USER}
$user
$USER
%user%
%USER%

changes
changes
subversion revision: 400
subversion revision: 400
```

As you can see, only the subversion revision expands correctly. The changes is empty for this particular job, so ignore that.

How do YOU define parameters in email? Any suggestions? 
I am using Hudson version 1.395

Comment: This question just earned med the "Tumbleweed" badge for no votes, answers. Therefore I now start a bounty to learn more about possibilities for Hudon email configuration

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use a parameter like this one: `${ENV, var="USER"}`

And 'USER' is the same as 'user' - you need to give then different names.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I am looking forward to try this at work next week.

Answer (score 3):

On top of what Rene suggests (that is, to use `${ENV, var="USER"}`) I believe you need to install yet another [plugin called 'email-ext'](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Email-ext+plugin).
I found that information in [some other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484058/are-setenv-hudson-plugin-variables-accessible-in-status-email) (there's no accepted answer though).

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I forgot to write that the plugin is needed (i refer to its configuration settings anyway).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but asking the user to enter their username is kinda redundant, and can be spoofed.

Hudson already knows who triggered the build (you can see it in the build's page), however it does not expose this into a variable. There is a [Job-Exporter](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Job+Exporter+Plugin) plugin that exports this information (and more) into a file in the workspace. It will be under `build.user.name` property.

From there, you can use the [EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) Plugin, supply it with this exported properties file (`hudsonBuild.properties`), and you will have an environment variable called `build.user.name` available to be used in the email as `${ENV, var="build.user.name"}`